# Categories not properly displayed in Orgmode Agenda Views

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I sort all my TODOs into PROJECTS, and that projects get a 4 letter abbreviation as category (using

```
#+CATEGORY: PPPP
```

The category is displayed in the first column of the agenda view. Unfortunately, with the latest update of org-mode by Jan 2018, only the last category of the file is displayed, in all lines. Do I have to adjust my org-mode settings?

Thanks in advance
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#+CATEGORY: PPPP` is a buffer-wide setting, so it applies to the whole file (and indeed the last setting wins). If you want categories for headings, you have to use a CATEGORY property:

```
* project foo
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CATEGORY: foo
  :END:
```

Comment: Yes, that does it. I tried it myself with a few entries without success, but I understand that all my former entries must be changed. I think that it is new because I have used the old way for a long time now.

Comment: See [etc/ORG-NEWS](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS#L1467): it is mentioned as an incompatible change for version 8.3 (and the entry indicates that the practice has been deprecated since version 5.14 back in 2008). The commit itself (80bccca) dates from 2015-03-31.

Comment: Here is commit [80bccca](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/80bccca4e249cbb5812963863ccffbdcf4b25edd).